# How to find the sum of a geometric series for which $a_4 =-80$, $a_7=640$, and $n=12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

In the following exercise how can I find $a_1$ or $r$ (common ratio).

Find the sum of a geometric series for which $a_4 =-80$, $a_7=640$, and $n=12$.

Comment: What does $n$ mean in this context?

Comment: n represent the amount of terms in the sequence.

Comment: Don't understand its relevant to this question, which is why I asked

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
a_7/a_4=r^3
$$
and
$$
a_1=a_4/r^3
$$

Comment: Thanks! So that means that $a_1=10$ and $r=-2$, right?

Comment: @eniid15 Yes that is correct.